# Install PostGIS on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial

Tags: postgresql, postgis, ubuntu-16.04

I want to install PostGIS 2.3 with PostgreSQL 9.6 on a Ubuntu xenial 16.04 with:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt trusty-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install postgis:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.3
```

But this returns:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

postgis : Depends: libgdal1h (>= 1.9.0) but it is not installable
          Depends: libgeos-c1 (>= 3.4.2) but it is not installable
          Depends: liblwgeom-2.3-0 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
```

Comment: Yep, I also ran into some conflicts like this when upgrading and had to uninstall some other stuff to get this working. Please try `sudo aptitude install` instead of `apt-get install` that gives you more options. I chose to uninstall some stuff and put in postgis.

Comment: I get the same results using `aptitude`,  can you be more specific on your approach?

Comment: aptitude shows you what the conflicts are and asks you how you wish to handle them.

Comment: Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     liblwgeom-2.3-0 [Not Installed]
2)     postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.3 [Not Installed]

Comment: surely it would have given you another option

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit later but for those who get this problem, try 
setting xenial-pgdg instead of trusty-pgdg when using 16.04

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt xenial-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list' 
wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo apt-get update
```