# Install postgis 2.2.1 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: postgresql, postgis, ubuntu-18.04

Is it possible to install postgreSQL extension 'postgis' version 2.2.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 even if it is not listed anywhere in packages? The only version available is 2.4.4 and I have upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 and there were not such issues.

I have tried aptitude and solution related to 
[Install PostGIS on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242173/install-postgis-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial)

And when somehow I have found the package, trying to install it returned similar errors, which are:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

postgis : Depends: libgdal1h (>= 1.9.0) but it is not installable
          Depends: libgeos-c1 (>= 3.4.2) but it is not installable
          Depends: liblwgeom-2.3-0 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
```

I have also tried all commands like:

```
sudo apt-get update, upgrade, -f install  etc.
```

Has anyone encountered similar issue? Is there some kind of a workaround? I really need this particular version of postgis in order to run application. Using postgis 2.4.4 causes trouble with thegeom. For now the only solution I have is to install Ubuntu 16.04 again.

Comment: did you ever solve this?  i also need a previous version of postgis and seem to be screwed.

Comment: unfortunately no, I had to switch back to Ubuntu 16.04